# Ext JS 4:Remove or update specific filter in Store

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a weird situation. I have multiple filters applied to same store LOCALLY. But whenever there is a new value, I have to update a specific filter (either delete and create or update).
Therefore I can't use store.clearFilter as it clears everything.

I tried

```
                            store.filters.removeAtKey(prop);

                    store.filters.add(prop, new Ext.util.Filter({
                      property: prop,
                      value: event.value
                    }));
```

No luck.

Any help appreciated

Tharahan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get all the filters before clean:

**store.filters**

```
var filtersAux = [];
// get filter
Ext.Array.each(store.filters.items,function(element,pos,array){
    // if Not (filter to remove)
    filtersAux.push(element);
});

// remove all filters
store.clearFilter();

// add the filters:
Ext.Array.each(filtersAux,function(element,pos,array){
    store.filter(element.property,element.value);
});
```

It work perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use the store's [`removeFilter`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-removeFilter) method instead?

```
// false prevents useless update until you've added the new filter
store.removeFilter(prop, false);
```

Comment: I think this is in 4.2x. I am using 4.1.3

Comment: Did you try to copy-paste the implementation from 4.2x source?